# GraphQl LightHouse Where Condition not working

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

How to add a `where` condition in query?

```
projects: [Project!]! @all @orderBy(column: "id", direction: DESC)
```

I'd like to have:

```
projects: [Project!]! @all @orderBy(column: "id", direction: DESC) @where('parent_id','=',0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Adding a where condition was too easy but was not clear in lighthouse docs.

projects(query: QueryCondition): [Project!]!
        @all
        @orderBy(column: "id", direction: DESC)

input QueryCondition {
    parent_id: ID @eq
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://lighthouse-php.com/5/api-reference/directives.html#all Look at `scope` argument on @all directive and read about https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes. This is what you need. @where directive can be passed only on arguments.

Comment: @Bartomiej Gajda
Not actually required. For Scope
Added my ANSWER BELOW

Answer (score 0):

You can put the [`@where`](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#where) with an optional `Int` and add a `orderBy` attribute with directive [`@orderBy`](https://lighthouse-php.com/master/api-reference/directives.html#orderby) like:

```
projects(
    parent_id: Int @where(key: "parent_id")
    orderBy: _@orderBy(columns: ["id"])
): [Project!]! 
    @all
```